# Identifying how many input/fields in a form?

Tags: jquery, if-statement

Identifying how many fields in each form and will do something with its category.

MQL form =  “data-mql = yes”

5 fields form = 4 input + 1 select

2 field form - 2 input

Not sure how should I include it into the if statement? I try to var the length, but it keeps go into the 5 fields form when I click on the 2 fields. **I am not allowed to change any HTML, which cannot add any attribution into the form.

Trying to

```js
var emailInput = form.getFormElem().find("input[name='Email']").length;
var firstnameInput = form.getFormElem().find("input[name='FirstName']").length;
var lastnameInput = form.getFormElem().find("input[name='LastName']").length;
var companyInput = form.getFormElem().find("input[name='Company']").length;
var countryInput = form.getFormElem().find("select[name='Country']").length;


$('.Form').on('click', function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      if ($(this).attr('data-mql') == "yes" || $(this).attr('data-mql') == "1") {
        alert("MQL");
      } else {
        if (emailInput >= 0 && firstnameInput >= 0 && lastnameInput >= 0 && companyInput >= 0 && countryInput >= 0) {
          alert(“five fields form ");
          }
          else if (emailInput >= 0 && countryInput >= 0) {
            alert(“two fields form ");
            }
          }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish? You have a potential logical error, please see:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND If any of those are FALSE or 0 value you might result in FALSE for the whole statement.

Comment: I am trying to: if click on a form that has 5 fields, then do something. I try to add >= 0, but still not working.

Comment: But what is the "*something*" you want to do? Please explain what you expect your code to do, along with the way(s) in which it's failing.

Comment: So if the user click on the Form; and the form has 5 Input Fields, So something like `count == 5`. If it has less or more, what should be done?

Comment: Where does `getFormElem()` come from? Is it part of some library?

Comment: getFormElem(), yes, is from Marketo. After knowing the form has 5 input fields, then pass a data to Adobe.

Comment: Note that you are using invalid quote characters (`“`) in your code, which should be throwing syntax errors in your console.

Comment: [HTMLFormElement.elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) Use the `.length` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  $('form').on('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var $self = $(this);
    var fieldCount = 0;
    fieldCount += $("input[name='Email']", $self).length;
    fieldCount += $("input[name='FirstName']", $self).length;
    fieldCount += $("input[name='LastName']", $self).length;
    fieldCount += $("input[name='Company']", $self).length;
    fieldCount += $("select[name='Country']", $self).length;
    if ($self.attr('data-mql') == "yes" || $self.attr('data-mql') == "1") {
      alert("MQL");
    } else {
      if (fieldCount == 5) {
        alert("five fields form");
      } else if (fieldCount == 2) {
        alert("two fields form");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When a Form is clicked upon, a variable is populated with the length of the fields. If that field does not exist the length will be 0. If 1 or more exists, it will return a single integer value equal to the number if inputs that match that selector (1, 2, 3...).

`fieldCount` will end up having some value between `0` and `n`. We can then use a logical statement to determine if that value is 5 or 2.

Comment: This is counting, but what if I have more than one form on the page? right now is counting on all the forms I have on the page instead of the form I click on.

Comment: @YanMak I updated the answer to be more dynamic and work for `$("form")` instead of `$(".Form")`

Comment: Just found another issue with the click, it fire 4 times, I try using .one/ .bind/ .unbind/ .off(event).. nothing working

Comment: @YanMak without seeing a Minimal, Reproducible Example ( https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ) I can't really help further.